# Wrong charset get_error_message() wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

There is PHP method in my API for handling POST requests:

```
...

$user_id = wp_create_user( $user_login, $user_pass, $user_login );

if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    $base_response['message'] = $user_id->get_error_message();
    $base_response['status'] = false;
    return json_encode ($base_response);
}

...
```

If user already exists, I get error message, but why this message ($base_response['message']) has unicode format: "u041du0430 u0436u0430u043bu044c, u0446u0435 u0456u043c'u044f u043au043eu0440u0438u0441u0442u0443u0432u0430u0447u0430 u0432u0436u0435 u0456u0441u043du0443u0454!". How to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in cyrillic language for wordpress site and json_encode could not correctly convert cyrillic message. When I changed the language in the wordpress admin to English, everything is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong parameter in `wp_create_user` function. You need to pass Email in last parameter instead of `user_login` .

```
$user_id = wp_create_user( $user_login, $user_pass, $user_email );

if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    $base_response['message'] = $user_id->get_error_message();
    $base_response['status'] = false;
    return json_encode ($base_response);
}
```

Refer document for correct parameter : 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_user/

Comment: The users have the same email address as the login. The problem is not in the adding of the user, but in the encoding. I was tested it, the problem is in json_encode

Comment: Please print and check this one : $user_id->get_error_message();

Comment: Thanks, but the problem was in cyrillic language for wordpress site and json_encode could not correctly convert cyrillic message. When I changed the language in the wordpress admin to English, everything is fine now.

Comment: I have tested iconv, but it did not work or I could not find the correct encoding. For me, only json_encode worked if you added JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE to the json_encode method, ie json_encode ($ base_response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), but it worked only with the simple test on a static php page with a сyrillic text. But it did not not work in the WordPress project, if the сyrillic language is selected in the wordpress system,, it only works if the English language is selected in the system.